# Can't figure out what I am doing wrong in this method ( compute_even )

Tags: java, methods, computation

I am having some problem understanding how I am supposed to do the compute_even method in this exercise, I hope someone can help me out.

Nevermind the compute_odd method I am still thinking about that one!

Here is the exercise:

Write a void method called choose_function that has a parameter n of type int. If the value of n is even the method will call the method compute_even passing to it value of the parameter n, else the method will call the method compute_odd passing to it the value of n.

The two methods will print on the console the following sequence:

compute_even: 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128… up to n

compute_odd: 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28 … up to n

Write program in which the user enter an int numbers n1 greater than zero (hence the program will prompt the user to enter a value until the condition is not satisfied). 
The program will print on the console the sequence associated to the value of n1.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n1;
    do
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a positive integer value: ");
        n1 = input.nextInt();
    }while(n1 <= 0);

    choose_function(n1);

    input.close();
}

public static void choose_function(int n)
{
    if(n%2 == 0)
        System.out.print(compute_even(n));
    else
        System.out.print(compute_odd(n));
}

public static int compute_even(int k)
{
    int r = 1;
    do
    {
        r = r*2;
        return r;
    }while(r <= k);
}

public static int compute_odd(int k)
{

}
```

strong text

Comment: Do you need to print all even/odd numbers from zero upto n1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this Code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n1;
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter a positive integer value: ");
        n1 = input.nextInt();
    } while (n1 <= 0);

    choose_function(n1);
    System.out.println();
    input.close();
}

public static void choose_function(int n) {
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        compute_even(n);
    } else {
        compute_odd(n);
    }
}

public static void compute_even(int k) {
    int r = 0;
    while (r <= k) {
    System.out.print(""+r+" ");
        r = r + 2;  
    } 
}
public static void compute_odd(int k) {
    int r = 1;
    while (r <= k){
        System.out.print(""+r+" ");
        r = r+2;   
    }
}
```

Try printing values inside `compute_odd` and `compute_even` method seperately. It seems there is a problem with your algorithm as well,

You should use

```
int r =0;
r = r+2 // returns 0 2 4 6 8...
```

instead of using

```
int r = 1;
r = r*2;  // This would return 2 4 8 16...
```

**Sample output :**

Enter a positive integer value:

-5

Enter a positive integer value:

5

1 3 5

Comment: Thanks a ton this really helped me understand it, but if you read the exercise what is asked is for the following sequence "even" 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128 etc...

Thanks to your comment I managed to get it!

I just replaced r starting value with 2 and the while now does r = r*2

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here.

```
int r = 1;
do
{
    r = r*2;
    return r;
} while(r <= k);
```

This code will return 2 every time to the caller. Why? Because in your loop, you set r = 1 * 2 = 2, then return r immediately. What you want to do instead is check if this new r is equal tot he passed parameter. If not, then print `r` and a space, and continue looping. If it IS equal, then print the final number and return from the method.

```
int r = 1;
do
{
    r = r*2;
    System.out.print(r + " ");
    if (r == k) return r;
}while(r <= k);
```